# Setting cookies with a button and showing values in view from cookie

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cookies

I am building a services rails app where a customer can order 3 different services but depending on the service selected there will be a different price and details.

I don't want to make a lot of forms for my order so I am attempting to make different order cookies that store an integer based on what button the user clicks on and then based on the cookies value it will display the order price and order details such as the turnaround time.

As of now I attempt to store cookies on button click like so `<%= link_to 'Package 1', controller:'order, action:'order_one'%>`

Defined in my routes like: `get 'order_one', to: 'order#order_one', as: 'order_one'` even though I have `resources: order` defined.

In my controller the `order_one` method is defined:

```
 def order_one
  cookies[:orderref]=1
  redirect_to '/order'
end
```

and calling a `before_action` on `capture_order` method which is `cookies[:orderref] = params[:orderref] if params[:orderref]`

At the moment when I click the button to the `order_one` link it just refreshes the home page so I'm unsure what I am doing wrong in setting this cookie.

**EDIT: order added**

```html
class OrderController < ApplicationController
  
  before_action :set_user, except: [:new, :create]
  before_action :set_admin, only: [:edit, :update, :destroy]
  before_action :capture_order_cookie

  def new
    @order = Order.new
    
    #TODO: Handling the cookie's here
    if cookies[:orderref] == 1 #Custom Text
      #TODO: price
    elsif cookies[:orderref] == 2 #Custom Text & Custom Imagery

    elsif cookies[:orderref] == 3 #Custom Text & Custom Cartoon
      #might run into a problem bc order isn't created and am trying to set price before creation, could just put price later on?
    end
    
  end
  
  def index
    #TODO: AJAX so order's disappear from view when status changes
    @orders = Order.all #TODO: maybe limit this?
    @orders_user = current_user.orders.where(status:2)
    @orders_user_completed = current_user.orders.where(status: 4 || 5)
    #Admin stuff
    @orders_active = @orders.where(status: 2) 
    @orders_review = @orders.where(status: 3) 
    @orders_completed_not_paid = @orders.where(status: 4) 
    @orders_all_completed = @orders.where(status: 5) 
    
  end
  
  def create
    @order = Order.where(order_params).first_or_create
    @order.status = 1
    if @order.save
      flash[:success] = "Order was successfully made"
      redirect_to root_path
    else
      #flash error
      flash[:error] = "Error making order"
      render 'new'
    end
  end
  
  def edit
    @order = set_order
  end
  
  def update
    @order = set_order
    if @order.update(order_params)
      flash[:success] = "Order was successfully updated"
      redirect_to dashboard_path
    else
      flash[:error] = "Error updating"
      render 'edit'
    end
  end
  
  def destroy
    #TODO: destroy for orders that were refunded/cancelled
  end
  
  #Accepting order & adding user_id to order
  def accept
    @order = set_order
    if @order.user_id.present?
      redirect_to root_path, flash[:error]='Order already taken'
    else
      @order.update(user_id: current_user.id)
      @order.update(status: 2)
      if @order.save
        redirect_to root_path, flash[:success]='Order accepted'
      else
        flash[:error]='Couldn`t process your request'
      end
    end
  end
  
  #Submitting order for review
  def submit
    @order = set_order
    @order.update(status: 3)
    if @order.save
      redirect_to dashboard_path, flash[:success]='Order submitted for review'
    else
      redirect_to dashboard_path, flash[:error]='Request failed'
    end
  end
  
  def order_one
    cookies.permanent[:orderref]=1
    redirect_to '/order'
  end
  
  private
  def order_params
    params.require(:order).permit(:name, :company, :email, :event_type, :status, :country, :description, :user_id, :admin_comments,
                                  :revision_comments)
  end
  
  def set_order
    @order = Order.find(params[:id])
  end
  
  def set_user
    if !current_user
      redirect_to root_path
    end
  end
  
  def set_admin
    if !current_user.admin
      if current_user
        redirect_to dashboard_path
      end
    redirect_to root_path
    end
  end
  
  def capture_order_cookie #could do the IFs here?
    cookies.permanent[:orderref] = params[:orderref] if params[:orderref]
  end
end
```

Comment: did you inspect and verified that the cookie is being set or not?

Comment: @Md.FarhanMemon it isn't being set and i'm wondering why

Comment: try `cookies.permanent[:orderref]`.

Comment: @Md.FarhanMemon that does not work either

Comment: can you post your whole controller?

Comment: @Md.FarhanMemon added it !

Comment: are you sure `if params[:orderref]` is true in your case? can you verify that?

Comment: @Md.FarhanMemon unsure how to do that but am guessing it isn't true due to the cookie failing to be set in the first place?

Comment: Write an if block and puts a string inside..you see if it goes in or not

Comment: @Md.FarhanMemon it doesn't return anything so it isn't being set

Comment: Exactly..now try printing params..your params doesn't contain that key

Comment: in the console this appears `Filter chain halted as :set_user rendered or redirected`

Comment: how do i fix this issue @Md.FarhanMemon

Comment: that's the desire behavior right? If user is not logged in, it should redirect..if you still want to save cookie then write it on top.

Comment: How important is it that this is done using cookies? Are they used for anything else in the application or were they just a possible solution to the general problem of you have different packages that need to share the same form but have different values? There are easier ways to accomplish that.

Comment: @SimpleLime they aren't used anywhere else I just thought that this would be the easiest option and make the rails app faster?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on not needing to use the cookies (they were just a possible solution found, see the comments on the question). I'd propose a different solution.

So first off you could just pass a query parameter to `/orders/new?orderref=1` (which I assume is where your meant to send them when you did `redirect_to '/order'`, since that would be the index action)

```
<%= link_to 'Package 1', new_order_path(orderref: 1) %>
```

and access it in the controller with `params[:orderref]` (this'll be a string) and set things in motion based on that.

If you don't want to do that, the next easiest would probably be to set up routes with a default parameter:

**config/routes.rb**

```
get 'order_one', to: 'orders#new', defaults: { orderref: 1 }, as: :order_one
get 'order_two', to: 'orders#new', defaults: { orderref: 2 }, as: :order_two
get 'order_three', to: 'orders#new', defaults: { orderref: 3 }, as: :order_three
```

**app/controllers/orders_controller.rb**

```
def new
  @order = Order.new

  # TODO: setup custom pricing, etc. here
  case params[:orderref]
  when 1
    @message = "Here with order 1"
  when 2
    @message = "Order Ref is 2"
  when 3
    @message = "Received the third"
  else
    @message = "No Order Ref received"
  end
end
```

**app/views/orders/new.html.erb**

```
<%= content_tag(:small, @message) %>
```

and finally your link to the page

```
<%= link_to 'Package 1', order_one_path %>
<%= link_to 'Package 2', order_two_path %> 
<%= link_to 'Package 3', order_three_path %>
```

now you can route your users to `/order_one` and they will go through your `new` action, while staying on the `/order_one` route (instead of being pushed into `/orders/new`).

If you want to make them go to `/orders/new` you can instead just use the `session`

**config/routes.rb**

```
get 'order_four', to: 'orders#order_four'
```

**app/controllers/orders_controller.rb**

```
def new
  @order = Order.new

  case session[:orderref]
  when 4
    @message = "From session"
  else
    @message = "No Order Ref received"
  end

  # clear the value from the session, so it's not lingering around
  # maybe you'll want to do this after creating an order?
  session[:orderref] = nil if session[:orderref]
end

# Might need to add this to the `:except` list for `set_user`
def order_four
  session[:orderref] = 4

 redirect_to new_order_path
end
```

and this'll keep them on `/orders/new` instead of custom urls per package with no query parameters, if that's a requirement.

Answer (score 0):

As discussed in the comments, `set_user` method is redirecting you to `root_url`, if you anyway want to save cookie even if user is not logged in then move the filter to first line as

```
before_action :capture_order_cookie
before_action :set_user, except: [:new, :create]
before_action :set_admin, only: [:edit, :update, :destroy]
```

Also, `set_user` method is not what it should, rename it as say `verify_session` or if you are using devise, it has a helper `authenticate_user`.

Comment: When i use the `authenticate_user!` it doesn't allow me to have certain actions pass the authentication part. For example, I don't want a user to be required to create an order but I do want one required to edit one.

Comment: ok, that was just a suggestion, it's up to you. Does the above code fix your bug?

Comment: no sorry, it still just refreshes and there is no cookie being set. I added a puts to my `order_one` and that isn't being rendered in the console